# Is there a canonical list of Latinized names?

Tags: vocabulary, names, reference-request

I'm not only talking about names that existed during the classical period, but also the standard Latinization of modern European names; for example *hugo, hugonis* is the standard medieval Latin rendering of "Hugh"; *ioannes, ioannis* for "John", and so on.

Is there some reference where I can find these standard Latin versions of common names?

Answer (score 5):

I think English-Latin dictionaries are your best choice here. For instance, [this dictionary](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryenglis02ainsuoft) has 6 pages of "Christian names" (and some surnames) in Latin. Other examples are pages 311-2 of [this dictionary](https://archive.org/details/completeenglishl00ridd), and page 927 of [this one](https://archive.org/details/cassellslatindic00marc). There is also a [Wikipedia list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_forms_of_English_given_names) (although it is sorted in Latin). Unfortunately this list has no references, so I would double check them with the lists above.